# App Store Submission Categories

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, categories, submission

I'm looking for submiting my iPad application into the App Store. The application is designed for teaching kids numbers and letters.

Where can I find an appropriate category for the application? Are there specific subcategories, e.g. "Math", or just general categories like "Education"?

I was told there are specific subcategories, but could only [this general list.](http://www.appsolutegenius.com/blog/appstoreategories/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want your first category to be Education. Then you'll want your secondary category to be Games. Games will allow you two subcategories which include Educational and Kids. That should do it :)

[image]